# Should I use async await for this example

Tags: javascript, async-await

It seems that the following example works both with **async await** like this:

```
import { db } from '../firebase';

const onAdd = async () => {
    await db.collection('FlashCards').add({
      originalText: newOriginalText,
      translatedText: newTranslatedText,
    });

  };
```

And without async await like this:

```
import { db } from '../firebase';

const onAdd = () => {
    db.collection('FlashCards').add({
      originalText: newOriginalText,
      translatedText: newTranslatedText,
    });

  };
```

Does it make any difference which one I use?
Does using async await improve anything in this example?

Comment: Is there any condition where you need to wait for `onAdd` to finish?

Comment: Does `db.collection('FlashCards').add(...)` return a promise? Do you want the code following `onAdd()` to "wait" for the operation to be completely done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the first snippet. It does have an advantage - you can wait for the `onAdd` to finish if you wish. With the second example, you can execute it and the code *would work* - an insertion would be made, however you cannot wait for the completion.

Here is a simple example:

```js
//simple delayed operation - prints a message after 2 seconds
async function delayedOperation(msg) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("complete:", msg);
      
      resolve();
    }, 2000);
  });
}

//awaiting the operation
async function withAwait() {
  await delayedOperation("with await");
}

//not awaiting the operation
function withoutAwait() {
  delayedOperation("without await");
}

async function main() {
  console.log("before calling withAwait()");
  await withAwait();
  console.log("after calling withAwait()");
  
  console.log("before calling withoutAwait()");
  await withoutAwait();
  console.log("after calling withoutAwait()");
}

main();
```

As you can see, the `withoutAwait` cannot itself be awaited. The problem is that it doesn't produce a promise, `main()` completes before the delayed operation in `withoutAwait()` finishes.

You can always *have* the `await` in the function but not use it, if it's not needed:

```js
async function delayedOperation(msg) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("complete:", msg);
      
      resolve();
    }, 2000);
  });
}

async function withAwait() {
  await delayedOperation("with await");
}

async function main() {
  console.log("before calling withAwait()");
  //not awaiting because we don't care whether it finishes before proceeding
  withAwait(); 
  console.log("after calling withAwait()");
}

main();
```

However, it's a good idea to check if the operation is completed, otherwise you cannot respond to errors or may not even know they happened:

```js
//WILL FAIL!
async function delayedOperation(msg) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {      
      reject(`problem when doing [${msg}]`);
    }, 2000);
  });
}

async function withAwait() {
  await delayedOperation("with await");
}

async function main() {
  console.log("before calling withAwait() and handling the error");
  try {
    await withAwait(); 
  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
  console.log("after calling withAwait() and handling the error");
  
  console.log("before calling withAwait() - no handling");
  //not awaiting because we don't care whether it finishes before proceeding
  withAwait(); 
  console.log("after calling withAwait() - no handling");
}

main();
```

And a note, adding `async` but *not* `await` will not allow you to correctly `await` the result of the function.

```js
async function delayedOperation(msg) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("complete:", msg);
      
      resolve();
    }, 2000);
  });
}


// async function but not awaiting the operation
async function withoutAwait() {
  delayedOperation("without await");
}

async function main() {
  console.log("before calling withoutAwait()");
  //attempting to await the completion
  await withoutAwait();
  console.log("after calling withoutAwait()");
}

main();
```

Since the body of the `withoutAwait()` doesn't have an `await` then it completes as soon as `delayedOperation()` returns a promise, rather than when that promise settles.

Answer (score 1):

It depends which behavior do you expect.
As mentioned in Firebase documentation, `.add(...)` method is async.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document

Await/Async functions ensure you storage execution is complete.
If you do not need to ensure data is stored in your DB after `onAdd` function call, you can do without async.

Answer (score 1):

**Async/Await** will ensure that your process will execute synchronously. so until finishing the **onAdd()** execution rest of the code will not be process. though it is depending on your context whether it is need or not.

but as per your context, i think **Async/Await** will be best.